# Bulk extraction of answer text?

Tags: support

It has crossed my mind more than once to use some of what I consider to be my better answers here as the basis for my own blog.

Is there a way for me to easily extract my answers from RPG.SE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not now, but *when* RPG.SE becomes a full fledged site, you will be able to download all your answers via [OData](http://data.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

"Easily" is kind of a relative term. In addition to the OData mentioned by C. Ross, there's also [the API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/), and [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/).